# java spring Long[] (array) type

Tags: java, sql, spring

If i have the next code

```
/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the Event entity.
 */
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>{
    @Query("SELECT id, name FROM event WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    List<EventItem> findEvents(@Param("ids") Long[] ids);
}
```

And want to use it

```
Long[] ids = new Long[3];
ids[0] = new Long(1);
ids[1] = new Long(2);
ids[2] = new Long(3);
eventRepository.findEvents(ids);
```

How to use correctly. I'm a beginner user in Spring-framework. I want to get some records with particulary id-s in the same time.

Comment: What is EventItem? A DTO or a Interface?

Comment: Update you question with mapping of Event and EventItem and Implementation of EventRepository

Comment: The event item is interface like the next:
package com.mysite.project.repository;

import java.util.Date;

public interface EventItem {

    Long getId();

    String getName();

}

Answer (score 0):

use the JPA `@NamedQuery`  i.e.

**Event Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
@NamedQuery(name = "Event.fetchEventItem",
        query = "SELECT id, name FROM event WHERE id IN (:ids)"
)
public class Event {
....
}
```

**Your Interface**

```
 @Repository
    public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>{
        List<EventItem> findEvents(Long[] ids);
    }
```

**Interface implements class**

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EventRepositoryImpl implements EventRepository {
 @PersistenceContext
 EntityManager entityManager;

     @Override
        public List<EventItem> findEvents(Long[] ids) {
        List<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>();
         Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c");
            Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Event.fetchEventItem", Event.class);
            query.setParameter(1, ids);
            list = query.getResultList();

            // Here You can Prapared List<EventItem>

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA provides you keywords inside method names to do this, so in your EventRepository class, add a method by following name:

```
List<Event> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
```

You can find several keywords inside method names which are wrapped just calling by its format that JPA provides.

**REFERENCES**

Table 2.3 Supported keywords inside method names ->

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html